# Material UI active Tab center align

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, material-ui

Is there any possibility to place active tab at the horizontal center of the screen, except situation when first or last tab is selected?

```
        <Tabs 
          className={classes.tabs}
          indicatorColor='primary'
          scrollButtons='auto'
          textColor='primary'
          value={activeTab}
          variant='scrollable'
        >
          {tabs.map(({ label, url, icon = '', id, action } => (
            <Tab
              key={id}
              label={label}
              icon={icon}
              onClick={onClick}
            />
          ))}
        </Tabs>
```

`activeTab` is calculated from current path.

`onClick` just pushes path changes with clicked tab id

[Active tab not in center screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXLc5.png)

[Active tab in center screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nec88.png)

Is it possible to make 2nd example situation automatically after tab click?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Comment: yes its possible

Comment: @NishargShah I have nothing special in code. I've added example above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You just have to create an `onClick` event (or, in vanilla Javascript an `onclick` event) which runs a `function`. The `function` it is running should hide the tab to be hidden and show the tab to be shown, as long as the index is not 0 and not length - 1.

Presumably you already have an event handler, since your question suggests that tab activation works. You will just have to implement the `function` I described above and trigger it in the event.

Comment: I have an `onClick` handler but I don't know how to hide/show Material UI Tab? If Tabs don't fit the screen width, they are just hidden by css overflow property. It's standard MUI behavior.

Comment: @АртёмГанев if you can create a fiddle or a snippet then I could take a look.

Comment: Here is a simple example https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-0qryh?file=/demo.tsx Nothing really special. You can open sandbox in new window and use Mobile device mode in Dev Tools.

Comment: please, check link above